# No se como acceder al valor de un boton usando el this

Tags: javascript, html, html5, javascript-objeto

tengo 9 botones tipo 3x3 en los que si el select esta sleccionado como subir cada vez que haga click en un boton tiene que aumentarse +1 el boton y si esta seleccionado en bajar tiene reducirse en -1 pero no consigo hacerlo y en clase me han dicho que use el this y no se como funciona

```
function ejercicio2(){
    var boton=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var desplegable=document.getElementById("lista1");
    alert(boton.value);
    if(desplegable.value=='subir'){
        this.value++;
    }else{
        this.value--;
    }
}

<div id="ejercicio2" style="padding: 15px">
        EJERCICIO 2 <br>
        <button name="boton" id="b1" onclick="ejercicio2()">0</button>
        <button name="boton" id="b2" onclick="ejercicio2()">0</button>
        <button name="boton" id="b3" onclick="ejercicio2()">0</button><br>
        <button name="boton" id="b4" onclick="ejercicio2()">0</button>
        <button name="boton" id="b5" onclick="ejercicio2()">0</button>
        <button name="boton" id="b6" onclick="ejercicio2()">0</button><br>
        <button name="boton" id="b7" onclick="ejercicio2()">0</button>
        <button name="boton" id="b8" onclick="ejercicio2()">0</button>
        <button name="boton" id="b9" onclick="ejercicio2()">0</button>
        <select name="lista" id="lista1">
            <option value="subir">Subir</option>
            <option value="bajar">Bajar</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el **HTML** para que podamos tener el escenario al completo?

Comment: Deberias insertar el HTML que estas utilizando para poder dar una respuesta acertada. Si estas utilizando `<button>` para obtener el "valor" debes usar `innerHTML` ya que `value` es para elementos `<input>`

Comment: Lo que te están pidiendo es que uses `this` para referirte al elemento pulsado **dentro de la función que pasas a `addEventListener`**

Comment: ye he añadido el html que me lo pidio phpMiguel creo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conseguirlo lo que podrías hacer es pasarle el `this` como parámetro de entrada a la función del `onclick`, de esta manera el `this` hace referencia al elemento que disparó el evento `click` por lo que podrías interactuar solamente con este en vez de con todos los botones.

Hay que tener en cuenta que para operar matemáticamente con el contenido de cada botón (para sumarle 1 o restarle 1) hay que transformarlo primero a `integer` a través de la función `parseInt()`

```html
<div id="ejercicio2" style="padding: 15px">
  EJERCICIO 2 <br>
  <button name="boton" id="b1" onclick="ejercicio2(this)">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b2" onclick="ejercicio2(this)">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b3" onclick="ejercicio2(this)">0</button><br>
  <button name="boton" id="b4" onclick="ejercicio2(this)">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b5" onclick="ejercicio2(this)">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b6" onclick="ejercicio2(this)">0</button><br>
  <button name="boton" id="b7" onclick="ejercicio2(this)">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b8" onclick="ejercicio2(this)">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b9" onclick="ejercicio2(this)">0</button>
  
  <select name="lista" id="lista1">
    <option value="subir">Subir</option>
    <option value="bajar">Bajar</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
  function ejercicio2 (boton) {
    let valor = boton.innerText;

    if (lista1.value == 'subir') {
       boton.innerText = parseInt(valor) + 1;
    }
    else {
       boton.innerText = parseInt(valor) - 1;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: FUNCIONA!!! joder todo el mundo le sale en clase en un momento y yo en una hora no lo sacaba menos mal que estais por aqui todos muchas gracias ^^

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de hacer todos los `onclick` podŕias agregar un listener, y en la función que se le pasa por parámetro ya está el `this`.

```js
const option = document.getElementById("lista1");

[...document.getElementsByName("boton")].forEach(boton => {
  boton.addEventListener("click", function() {

    //Aqui "this" es cada elemento

    (option.value === 'subir') ? this.innerText++: this.innerText--;
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="ejercicio2" style="padding: 15px">
  EJERCICIO 2 <br>
  <button name="boton" id="b1">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b2">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b3">0</button><br>
  <button name="boton" id="b4">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b5">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b6">0</button><br>
  <button name="boton" id="b7">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b8">0</button>
  <button name="boton" id="b9">0</button>
  <select name="lista" id="lista1">
    <option value="subir">Subir</option>
    <option value="bajar">Bajar</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Mucha mejor opción, aunque quizás exceda el nivel de un ejercicio de aprendizaje básico.